# Calculation of charge transport with the non-orthogonal basis Hamiltonian based on the non-equilibrium Green's function method

Tags: density-functional-theory, electronic-transport, transport, greens-functions

I am thinking about one question. If the Hamiltonian matrix is based on the non-orthogonal basis, how to compute the charge conductance with the Non-Equilibrium Green's Function (NEGF) method.

Suppose the Hamiltonian of the system is denoted by $H$ and the overlap matrix is denoted by $S$. They are written below.

\begin{align}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\left(\varepsilon_{F}+i\right)S-H&=\varepsilon^{'}S-H\tag{1}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon^{'}S_{ll}-H_{ll}&\varepsilon^{'}S_{ls}-H_{ls}&0\tag{2}\\
\varepsilon^{'}\times S_{sl}-H_{sl}&\varepsilon^{'} S_{ss}-H_{ss}&\varepsilon^{'} S_{sr}-H_{sr}\\0&\varepsilon^{'} S_{rs}-H_{rs}&\varepsilon^{'} S_{rr}-H_{rr}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}H^{'}_{ll}&H^{'}_{ls}&0\\H^{'}_{sl}&H^{'}_{ss}&H^{'}_{sr}\\0&H^{'}_{rs}&H^{'}_{rr}\end{pmatrix}.\tag{3}
\end{align}

Here, $\varepsilon_{F}$ is the Fermi energy level of the central scattering zone and $i$ is the imaginary number.

\begin{align}
G_{ll}&=\left[H^{'}_{ll}\right]^{-1}\tag{4} \\ G_{rr}&=\left[H^{'}_{rr}\right]^{-1}\tag{5} \\
\Gamma_\text{left}&=H^{'}_{sl} G_{ll} H^{'}_{ls}\tag{6} \\ \Gamma_\text{right}&=H^{'}_{sr} G_{ll} H^{'}_{rs}\tag{7}
\end{align}

Self energy for the left and right leads and the green function for the scattering zone are written below:
\begin{align}
\Sigma_\text{left}&=i \times \left[\Gamma_\text{left}-\left(\Gamma_\text{left}\right)^{+}\right] \tag{8} \\
\Sigma_\text{right}&=i \times \left[\Gamma_\text{right}-\left(\Gamma_\text{right}\right)^{+}\right]\tag{9} \\
G_{ss}^{R}&=\left[H^{'}_{ss}-\Gamma_\text{left}-\Gamma_\text{right}\right]^{-1}\tag{10} \\
G_{ss}^{A}&=\left(G_{ss}^{R}\right)^{+}\tag{11}
\end{align}

Then, the charge conductance is written below:

$$G_{k}=\frac{2e^{2}}{h}\mathrm{Tr}\left[\Sigma_\text{left}G_{ss}^{A}\Sigma_\text{right}G_{ss}\right]\tag{12}$$

This conductance is only for one single k point in the reciprocal space. The total charge conductance is the integral of this single-k-point-conductance over the whole first Brillouin zone.

$$G_{\textrm{total}}=\frac{e}{h}\int G_{k}\times \left[f_{(\varepsilon_{F}-\mu_\text{left})}-f_{(\varepsilon_{F}-\mu_\text{right})}\right]d_{k}\tag{13}$$

where, $f_{(\varepsilon_{F}-\mu_\text{left})}$ and $f_{(\varepsilon_{F}-\mu_\text{right})}$ are Fermi-Dirac distribution function for left and right leads with the chemical potential $\mu_\text{left}$ and $\mu_\text{right}$ for the left and right leads.

To calculate the surface green function in equation (4) and (5), I used the Sancho's method.<sup>[1]</sup>

#### The final conductivity value, $G_{\textrm{total}}$, is only correct at the $\Gamma$ point in the reciprocal space, but wrong at other k points.

I checked the internal output data and found that the calculation of the Surface Green's function was not right, since some data was `NaN` type. I guess this is because I did not use the correct way to avoid the singular matrix in the Surface Green's function calculation step.

**Would anyone please give me some suggestions on the solution?**

---

##### References

1. M. P. L. Sancho, J. M. L. Sancho and J, Rubio, Highly convergent schemes for the calculation of bulk and surface Green functions, J. Phys. F: Met. Phys. 15 (1985) 851-858.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer? Also, it would be nice for you to number all of your equations (even if they are never referenced, so that when *other* people are referencing them, they can say "Eq. 6 of this MMSE question", rather than "the sixth equation in this MMSE question"). Also $G_{\rm{total}}$ looks better than $G_{total}$ so fi you can fix the subscripts for words like "total", "right" and "left", that would be helpful!

Comment: @Nike Thank you for the comment. Yes, I still need an answer. At this moment, I have successfully programmed NEGF method to compute the conductivity at Gamma point in the reciprocal space; however, I found that conductivity value is wrong at other k point in the reciprocal space. I checked the internal output data and found that the calculation of the surface green function was not right since some data was 'NaN' type. I guess this is because I did not use the correct way to avoid the singular matrix in the surface green function calculation step. Would anyone please give me some suggestions?

Comment: @Nike On the other hand, I am not acquainted with Latex command. I do not know how to add equation number and change the font of $G_{total}$ as you suggested. Would you please help me modify it? Thank you.

Comment: You can use `\tag{5}` to number an equation with the number 5. For subscripts in Roman font, you can use `\textrm{}` around the text.

Comment: More equation numbers would be appropriate, because right now we'd have to say "the Eq. before Eq. 1" or "the fourth equation between Eq. 1 and Eq. 2" to refer to some equations.

Comment: @Nike Thank you for the suggestions. I modified my posted question again with more details of the problem I am currently facing. Would you please recommend my question to any expert in the non-equilibrium green function method or transport calculation? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I can help you with advertising the question, but first the formatting needs to be more presentable. You have fixed the word "total" but not the words "left" and "right" (for example). I made a further edit to help you, and I'm going to flag the question to get more help from diamond moderators because there's more that can be improved. Your commas near equations 8 and 9 can be placed better, and you have also begun a sentence with the word "and" with a lower case `a`.

Comment: @Nike Thank you very much for the modification of the typo in my question. I do indeed need help about this NEGF method. I will wait for other experts' comments/suggestions.

Comment: I have added this question to a potential bounty list: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/377/5. By the way, you mentioned "other experts", is there anyone specifically that you have in mind, for whom you'd like us to bring this question to their attention?

Comment: Your equations looks correct. So my bet is that when you setup the k-points you are doing things wrong. It is pretty hard to decipher whether you are setting up the Hamiltonian (for all parts) correct, as the equations does not show *what* you did :)

Also, I think it is more customary to use $\Sigma$ as the self-energy, and $\Gamma$ as the scattering matrices.

Comment: @nickpapior Thank you for the reply. Previously, I used the Hamiltonian matrix to compute the band structure at all k points along the k path and the result was correct so I think that I extracted the Hamiltonian matrix in the correct way. I suspect that the problem was from the way I used to avoid the singular matrix for the surface green function calculation in equation 4 and 5. I added a small imaginary number (0.0d0, 1.0d-4) to all diagonal term in the matrix to avoid the singular matrix.

Comment: @nickpapior The final conductivity was correct the $\Gamma$ point but wrong at other k point in reciprocal space. Do you think the way I used to avoid the singular matrix is correct or not? Would you please recommend some other methods? Thank you again.

Comment: I think your imaginary value looks correct. A shift of the energy into the complex plane is all that is needed. 1e-4 seems fine. If the shift was wrong, then the Gamma-point would also yield wrong results. I would still think you do something wrong in the k-point setup. But I don't know, from the looks of it, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: @nickpapior Thank you for the suggestion. I used the pure copper nanowire, which is one dimensional system and has same copper in all left lead, scattering zone and right zone, to test my code. The periodicity is along the $z$ axis. I did the integral of the conductivity within the $x$-$y$ k point plane in the reciprocal space. I found that the conductivity value at $\Gamma$ point, was an integer number at any energy level; while, fractional number at other k points. I suppose the conductivity should be integer number at any k point. Do you think my understanding is right?

Comment: Yes, for individual k-points it should be like that.

Comment: @nickpapior Can I ask one more question? The transmission coefficient for the thermal conductance is also $T_{\omega}={Tr}\left[\Sigma_\text{left}G_{ss}^{A}\Sigma_\text{right}G_{ss}\right]$. [Jian-sheng Wang, Jian Wang and J. T. Lu, Eur. Phys. J. B 62, 381 (2008)]. It is same as that for the charge conductance. Is my understanding correct or not?

Comment: @Kieran  I suggest that you ask new questions in new posts, so that any of the 7500+ users can answer it, and so that the answer is not lost in a comment chain which might get deleted.0

Comment: @Nike Thank you for your suggestion. I have already posted a new question. The link is wirtten below.

Comment: @Nike https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/12325/difference-of-the-transmission-coefficient-between-thermal-and-charge-conductanc

Comment: @Nike Would you please recommend my new posted question to some experts? Thank you again.

Comment: @Kieran you can post a bounty on the question after 48 hours. Also, has this question been answered now?

Comment: @Nike Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Do you have the answer to this question from 9 months ago?

Comment: @Nike Thank you for your concern. After thinking about my own understanding of the NEGF, I think my calculation procedure for NEGF method is correct. The only problem may be from the way I extract the Hamiltonian, which is generated by DFT code. I need to double check the part, extracting the Hamiltonian matrix, in my own code again.